# Verify if a background is equal to another for Edit Text in Android

Tags: android, background, android-edittext

In my project I have to verify if a backround is equal to another for an edit text (the edit text has a custom drawable). I have tried this code but it's not working:

```
 if (editText.getBackground().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_box_red)))
 {
       editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_box_white);
 }
```

I need this, because when I press a button and my editText background is red I have to make it white, to it's previous state. How can I do this?

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832918/how-to-get-background-color-of-button-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would make sense to store the background information when you change the background in the first place. One way to do this would be [`setTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29). For example, when you change the view's background to red, you also perform `editText.setTag("red")`. Then later, you can do

```
if (editText.getTag().equals("red")) {
    editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_box_white);
    editText.setTag("white");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about "Flagging"?
Its like you create a `static bool red = false`
Then when you change the color, change the `red` value to `true`
In the selection :

```
if(red == true){
editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit_text_box_white);
red = false;}
```

Hope this help :D

Comment: Your answer is good too, but I think the UgglyNoodle option is better because I don't have to create another instance variable. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I agree with you, setTag() probably created for avoiding too much Flagging :D
Please consider to upvote my answer if you think its good enough(i'm a newbie here :D)
Good luck!